# vb.net get value from postgresql query

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I am trying to get a value from a query then use that query result for a conditional statement..
then, I made this function

```
Public Function compareyearnowctaxyear(ByVal maxctaxyear As Integer) As Integer
 maxctaxyear =
<string>     
select  distinct max(maxctaxyear) as maxctaxyear from view_delinquency_allquarter  where owner_id='<%= txtownerid.Text %>'           
</string>
Return maxctaxyear
End Function
```

The problem is that this function only returns 0
when I displayed it using this:

```
a = compareyearnowctaxyear(maxctaxyear) 
MessageBox.Show(a)
```

Comment: Why "select distinct max(maxctaxyear)". "select max(maxctaxyear)" is already returning a single value, you don't need to specify "distinct" clause. 
More: Param "ByVal maxctaxyear As Integer": are useless?

You have to say more about how are you getting the value from database ... I mean, tell us more about that <String></String> area that you are obviating.

Comment: I am using vb.net, the <String></String> was used to let the code be on next line

Comment: I just have to get the maximum number from view_delinquency_allquarter which is the maxctaxyear attribute

Comment: I need to get the maximum value of the number from the query

Comment: How are you connecting with PostgreSQL database?

Comment: ok, I supposed already you were not using a toaster :) 
Sorry I can't help you with this info. Regards http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve